# Replace null value with previous available value in Row SQL server query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking for building a query to replace null value with previous available values.can somebody help.Here is the table currently looking like

```
11/30/2015   ID1     CLassName   1
NULL         ID1     CLassName   2
NULL         ID1     CLassName   3
NULL         ID1     CLassName   4
11/30/2015   ID1     CLassName   5
NULL         ID1     CLassName   6
NULL         ID1     CLassName   7
12/31/2015   ID1     CLassName   1
NULL         ID1     CLassName   2
NULL         ID1     CLassName   3
NULL         ID1     CLassName   4
12/31/2015   ID1     CLassName   5
NULL         ID1     CLassName   6
NULL         ID1     CLassName   7
```

Output shall look like

```
11/30/2015       ID1     CLassName   1
11/30/2015       ID1     CLassName   2
11/30/2015       ID1     CLassName   3
11/30/2015       ID1     CLassName   4
11/30/2015       ID1     CLassName   5
11/30/2015       ID1     CLassName   6
11/30/2015       ID1     CLassName   7
12/31/2015       ID1     CLassName   1
12/31/2015       ID1     CLassName   2
12/31/2015       ID1     CLassName   3
12/31/2015       ID1     CLassName   4
12/31/2015       ID1     CLassName   5
12/31/2015       ID1     CLassName   6
12/31/2015       ID1     CLassName   7
```

Comment: As it is posted, there is nothing in the sample data to guarantee the order of the rows.  Any solutions that appear to work could fail at any time.

Answer (score 10):

The below statement working perfectly

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN DATE1 IS NULL 
     THEN 
(SELECT TOP 1 DATE1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID2<T.ID2 
  AND Date1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID2 DESC) ELSE Date1 END AS DATENEW,
*FROM Table1 T
```

The output like below

```
        DATENEW             Date1          ID   Class      ID2
        11/30/2015          11/30/2015     ID1  ClassName   1
        11/30/2015          NULL           ID1  ClassName   2
        11/30/2015          NULL           ID1  ClassName   3
        11/30/2015          NULL           ID1  ClassName   4
        12/31/2015          12/31/2015     ID1  ClassName   5
        12/31/2015          NULL           ID1  ClassName   6
        12/31/2015          NULL           ID1  ClassName   7
```

Answer (score 5):

This question is a bit old, but you can achieve the same thing using the `first_value` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with SQL Server (starting with 2012 version)

First, you can create a new column that contains an increasing number for each "block" of a non-null date and all the next null values:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Date1 is NULL then 0 else 1 END) AS block
    FROM your_table
)
```

This CTE will create something like this (I'm using the column names of Shakeer's answer):

```
Date1          ID   Class      ID2    block
11/30/2015     ID1  ClassName   1      1
NULL           ID1  ClassName   2      1
NULL           ID1  ClassName   3      1
NULL           ID1  ClassName   4      1
12/31/2015     ID1  ClassName   5      2
NULL           ID1  ClassName   6      2
NULL           ID1  ClassName   7      2
```

Now, you can use the `first_value` function to get the first value of each "block":

```
SELECT *,
        first_value(Date1) OVER (PARTITION BY block ORDER BY ID2) AS NewDate
FROM CTE
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but you need a group by statement in your SUM(CASE WHEN Date1 is NULL then 0 else 1 END) AS block code?

Comment: is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the code given below.

Note: Code not tested. Also, this code needs to consider if you need the previous value based on the ID column or any other requirement like that.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Date1 VARCHAR(10), ID VARCHAR(10), Class VARCHAR(10), ID2 INT);

INSERT INTO Table1 Values ('11/30/2015', 'ID1', 'ClassName', 1);
INSERT INTO Table1 Values (NULL, 'ID1', 'ClassName', 2);
INSERT INTO Table1 Values (NULL, 'ID1', 'ClassName', 3);
INSERT INTO Table1 Values (NULL, 'ID1', 'ClassName', 4);
INSERT INTO Table1 Values ('12/31/2015', 'ID1', 'ClassName', 5);
INSERT INTO Table1 Values (NULL, 'ID1', 'ClassName', 6);
INSERT INTO Table1 Values (NULL, 'ID1', 'ClassName', 7);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (Date1 VARCHAR(10), ID VARCHAR(10), Class VARCHAR(10), ID2 INT);

DECLARE @Date1 VARCHAR(10), @ID1 VARCHAR(10), @Class VARCHAR(10), @ID2 INT;
DECLARE @TempDate1 VARCHAR(10); --set default if first record is null

DECLARE CURSOR MYCUR FOR
SELECT Date1, ID1, Class, ID2
FROM Table1;
OPEN MYCUR
FETCH NEXT FROM MYCUR INTO @Date1, @ID1, @Class, @ID2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF (@Date1 IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        @TempDate1=@Date1
    END

    INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(@TempDate1, @ID1, @Class, @ID2)

    FETCH NEXT FROM MYCUR INTO @Date1, @ID1, @Class, @ID2
END

CLOSE MYCUR
DEALLOCATE MYCUR

SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Comment: Is there a simpler solution available using CTE .I am trying to solve this problem with less lines of code.

Comment: I tried running your code and it gives syntax error.Not sure if it is working code.

Comment: No, I was not able to run the code. Don't have the required tools right now. I just tried to give the approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work, I am assuming the table and column names since you have not provided these, also assuming `id`  is the column based on which you are ordering the rows

```
 UPDATE table1 T
    SET T.date1 = (
                     SELECT MAX(T2.date)
                       FROM table1 T2
                      WHERE T2.date IS NOT NULL
                        AND T2.id <= T.id
                  )
  WHERE T.date1 IS NULL
```

Comment: I tested out your solution it doesnt work since the Id column is having same values i.e Id1 so I cannot use the condition T2.id <= T.id ..

Comment: oh, by `id` I meant the last column which has the numbers ranging from 1 thru 7

Answer (score 0):

Working with MS Access the approach that worked for me was to add an autonumber (ID) field to establish a fixed order and then use an update statement with a copy of the source table and suitable where condition:

```
UPDATE Table, Table AS Table_1 SET Table.Field  = [Table_1].[Field]
WHERE (((Table_1.Field) Is Not Null) AND ((Table_1.ID)<[Table].[ID]));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Update statement.

The sample query to generate data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (Date1 date)

insert into Table1 values ('11/30/2015')
insert into Table1 values (NULL)
insert into Table1 values (NULL)
insert into Table1 values ('11/20/2016')
insert into Table1 values (NULL)
insert into Table1 values ('10/12/2017')
insert into Table1 values (NULL)
```

And the query with an Update Statement,

```
DECLARE @n date
UPDATE Table1 
SET 
    @n = COALESCE(DATE1, @n),
    DATE1 = COALESCE(DATE1, @n)

 SELECT * from table1
```

Output:

```
Date1
2015-11-30
2015-11-30
2015-11-30
2016-11-20
2016-11-20
2017-10-12
2017-10-12
```