# How can I fill the null values with the values up these nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I fill the null values with the values below these null values?

Example, I have a table like this:

```
Mat   Name
123   Jerry
Null  Mary
Null  Sam
456   Matt
Null  Harry
Null  Jin
```

but it should be like this:

```
Mat   Name 
123   Jerry
123   Mary
122   Sam
456   Matt
456   Harry
456   Jin
```

Can I achieve this in a select statement or do I have to use a function or a stored procedure?

Comment: Without seeing the select statement it's hard to say.  Can you include some sample data too, please?

Comment: Where does the value for Mat come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace null value with previous available value in Row SQL server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050674/replace-null-value-with-previous-available-value-in-row-sql-server-query)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
select name, max(value) OVER(ORDER BY name ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) as value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to add an `ID` column to your table (if you don't have one already) this query should work

```
declare @tbl as table (
    id int
    ,mat int
    ,name varchar(15)
)

insert into @tbl values (1,123, 'Jerry')
insert into @tbl values (2,NULL, 'Marry')
insert into @tbl values (3,NULL, 'Sam')
insert into @tbl values (4,456, 'Matt')
insert into @tbl values (5,NULL, 'Harry')
insert into @tbl values (6,NULL, 'Jin')

SELECT
    id
    ,CASE WHEN
        mat IS NULL THEN
            (SELECT TOP 1 mat FROM @tbl WHERE id<T.id AND mat IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC)
        ELSE mat
    END AS mat
    ,name
FROM @tbl T
```

Comment: possible duplicate answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050674/replace-null-value-with-previous-available-value-in-row-sql-server-query